# Adwords API parallel report error (multiprocessing broken pipe)

Tags: python, api, google-ads-api, python-multiprocessing, broken-pipe

Hopefully someone can help me. I am attempting to pull data through the Google AdWords API using Python. I need to pull data for multiple accounts stored under a single MCC.

Google has example code for doing this as a parallel download (https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/v201607/reporting/parallel_report_download.py).

However the example code errors with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File         "C:/Users/casper.nygaard/Documents/WebTv/youtube/YouTube_ParallelDataRetrieval.py", line 226, in <module>
main(adwords_client, REPORT_DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY)
File "C:/Users/casper.nygaard/Documents/WebTv/youtube/YouTube_ParallelDataRetrieval.py", line 85, in main
process.start()
File "C:\Users\casper.nygaard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
self._popen = self._Popen(self)
File "C:\Users\casper.nygaard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 212, in _Popen
return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
File "C:\Users\casper.nygaard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 313, in _Popen
return Popen(process_obj)
File "C:\Users\casper.nygaard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 66, in __init__
reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
File "C:\Users\casper.nygaard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 59, in dump
ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I am running python 3.5, and I think the example code is written in 2.7 (I had to add print parentheses and change exception handling syntax). But I do not know if my error is related.

As far as I can see the code errors on these lines:

```
for process in processes:
process.start()
```

I am no programming expert, and to be honest I have no idea how to debug this particular issue, so any help is much appreciated.

It is not a requirement that I run in parallel, so if anyone has example code for the AdWords API for running over multiple accounts without multiprocessing then that would also be welcome help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of report samples available here: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/tree/master/examples/adwords/v201609/reporting

It is a bit messy, but I am running this code, based on the download_criteria_report_with_awql.py sample. Enter the MCC account number at the end and it will crawl all of the child accounts. There are separate functions for campaign and adgroup reports.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from googleads import adwords
import datetime

# Specify where to download the file here.
d = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
file_date = int(d.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
FILE_DIRECTORY = './'
RESULT_FILE_NAME = ' ' + str(file_date) + '.csv'
PAGE_SIZE = 500
REPORT_PERIOD = 'LAST_7_DAYS'
# TODAY | YESTERDAY | LAST_7_DAYS | THIS_WEEK_SUN_TODAY | THIS_WEEK_MON_TODAY | LAST_WEEK |
# LAST_14_DAYS | LAST_30_DAYS | LAST_BUSINESS_WEEK | LAST_WEEK_SUN_SAT | THIS_MONTH | 20170101,20171231


def run_report(adwords_client, client_list):
import csv

print('Pulling AdWords API pull...')
first_run = True

for client in client_list:
    print('Reporting for ' + str(client))
    report = get_adgroup_report(adwords_client, client)
    report_array = report['report'].split('\n')
    reader = csv.reader(report_array, delimiter=',')

    print('Processing data to file...')
    if first_run:
        with open(FILE_DIRECTORY + '/' + RESULT_FILE_NAME, 'w', newline='\n', encoding='utf8') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            writer.writerow(report['headers'])
            first_run = False
            csv_file.close()
    else:
        do_cleaning(reader, report['headers'])

    # print('Report saved.')
print('Done pulling from AdWords API.')


def do_cleaning(reader, header):
import csv

# Fields that Google reports in micro amounts that need to be 'x / 1000000'
micro_array = ['AverageCpc', 'Cost', 'CostPerConversion', 'AverageCpc', 'TargetCpa', 'CpcBid']
# Fields that need to be cleaned and converted to percentages
percent_array = ['CampaignDesktopBidModifier', 'CampaignMobileBidModifier', 'CampaignTabletBidModifier',
                 'AdGroupDesktopBidModifier', 'AdGroupMobileBidModifier', 'AdGroupTabletBidModifier',
                 'SearchExactMatchImpressionShare', 'SearchExactMatchImpressionShare', 'SearchImpressionShare',
                 'SearchRankLostImpressionShare']

with open(FILE_DIRECTORY + '/' + RESULT_FILE_NAME, 'a', newline='\n', encoding='utf8') as csv_file:
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) > 1:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

            i = 0
            post_row = []
            for field in row:
                if field == ' --':
                    field = ''

                if header[i] in percent_array and field != '':
                    field = field.replace('%', '').replace('<', '').replace('>', '').replace(' ', '')
                    field = float(field) / 100

                if header[i] in micro_array and field != '':
                    field = int(field) / 1000000

                if isinstance(field, float):
                    field = round(field, 2)

                post_row.append(field)
                i += 1
            writer.writerow(post_row)
    csv_file.close()


def get_account_hierarchy(client, client_id):
# Initialize appropriate service.
client.SetClientCustomerId(client_id)
managed_customer_service = client.GetService('ManagedCustomerService', version='v201607')

# Construct selector to get all accounts.
offset = 0
selector = {
        'fields': ['CustomerId', 'Name'],
        'paging': {
                'startIndex': str(offset),
                'numberResults': str(PAGE_SIZE)
        }
}
more_pages = True
accounts = {}
child_links = {}
parent_links = {}
root_account = None
# Shell account numbers (accounts that only contain other accounts)
mcc_accounts = []

while more_pages:
    # Get serviced account graph.
    page = managed_customer_service.get(selector)
    if 'entries' in page and page['entries']:
        # Create map from customerId to parent and child links.
        if 'links' in page:
            for link in page['links']:
                if link['managerCustomerId'] not in child_links:
                    child_links[link['managerCustomerId']] = []
                child_links[link['managerCustomerId']].append(link)
                if link['clientCustomerId'] not in parent_links:
                    parent_links[link['clientCustomerId']] = []
                parent_links[link['clientCustomerId']].append(link)
        # Map from customerID to account.
        for account in page['entries']:
            if account['customerId'] not in mcc_accounts:
                accounts[account['customerId']] = account
    offset += PAGE_SIZE
    selector['paging']['startIndex'] = str(offset)
    more_pages = offset < int(page['totalNumEntries'])

# Find the root account.
for customer_id in accounts:
    if customer_id not in parent_links:
        root_account = accounts[customer_id]

return accounts


def get_campaign_report(client, client_id):
client.SetClientCustomerId(client_id)
report_downloader = client.GetReportDownloader(version='v201609')

columns = ['Date', 'AccountDescriptiveName', 'DayOfWeek', 'CampaignName', 'CampaignId', 'Device', 'Impressions',
           'Clicks', 'Conversions', 'AverageCpc', 'Cost', 'AveragePosition', 'CostPerConversion',
           'BiddingStrategyType', 'BiddingStrategyId', 'BiddingStrategyName', 'CampaignDesktopBidModifier',
           'CampaignMobileBidModifier', 'CampaignTabletBidModifier', 'SearchExactMatchImpressionShare',
           'SearchImpressionShare', 'SearchRankLostImpressionShare', 'CampaignTrialType', 'BaseCampaignId']
separator = ','
report_query = ('SELECT ' + separator.join(columns) + ' FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING ' + REPORT_PERIOD)

# with open('temp.csv', 'w') as output_file:
#    report_downloader.DownloadReportWithAwql(report_query, 'CSV', output_file, skip_report_header=True,
#                                             skip_column_header=False, skip_report_summary=True)

report = report_downloader.DownloadReportAsStringWithAwql(report_query, 'CSV', skip_report_header=True,
                                                          skip_column_header=True, skip_report_summary=True)
payload = {'report': report,
           'headers': columns
           }
# print('Report done.')
return payload


def get_adgroup_report(client, client_id):
client.SetClientCustomerId(client_id)
report_downloader = client.GetReportDownloader(version='v201609')

columns = ['Date', 'AccountDescriptiveName', 'DayOfWeek', 'CampaignName', 'CampaignId', 'AdGroupName', 'AdGroupId',
           'Device', 'Impressions', 'Clicks', 'Conversions', 'Cost', 'AverageCpc', 'CostPerConversion',
           'AveragePosition', 'BiddingStrategyType', 'BiddingStrategyId', 'BiddingStrategyName', 'CpcBid',
           'TargetCpa', 'AdGroupDesktopBidModifier', 'AdGroupMobileBidModifier', 'AdGroupTabletBidModifier',
           'BaseCampaignId', 'BaseAdGroupId']
separator = ','
report_query = ('SELECT ' + separator.join(columns) + ' FROM ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING ' + REPORT_PERIOD)

# with open('temp.csv', 'w') as output_file:
#    report_downloader.DownloadReportWithAwql(report_query, 'CSV', output_file, skip_report_header=True,
#                                             skip_column_header=False, skip_report_summary=True)

report = report_downloader.DownloadReportAsStringWithAwql(report_query, 'CSV', skip_report_header=True,
                                                          skip_column_header=True, skip_report_summary=True)

payload = {'report': report,
           'headers': columns
           }
# print('Report done.')
return payload


if __name__ == '__main__':
mcc_client_customer_id = 'MCC account number'
adwords_client =  adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage('adwords_credentials.yaml')
accounts = get_account_hierarchy(adwords_client, mcc_client_customer_id)
run_report(adwords_client, accounts)
```